# How this enum syntax works

Tags: syntax, arduino, enumeration, arduino-c++

I am trying to build a game for Arduino, so I searched for a starting point and got to this syntax:

```
enum DisplayItem upperItem = (DisplayItem)((graphicRam[x/(8/2)][y*2]>>((x%(8/2))*2))&0x3);
```

where I have the enum variable with it's states:

```
enum DisplayItem {GRAPHIC_ITEM_NONE, GRAPHIC_ITEM_A, GRAPHIC_ITEM_B, GRAPHIC_ITEM_NUM};
```

The `((graphicRam[x/(8/2)][y*2]>>((x%(8/2))*2))&0x3)` part is from the rest of the code and I think it can be treated as a simple integer. My question is how **(DisplayItem)(something)** works? I've tried to run a simpler code but this syntax **(enum variable)(x)** just give me an error.

Comment: The expression ends with `& 0x3` which forces the result to be 0, 1, 2, or 3. The enum values are also 0, 1, 2, or 3. The `(DisplayItem)(value)` syntax is a cast. It tells the compiler that the `value` shall be interpreted as the corresponding enum value. Which is to say that it actually does nothing except avoid a compiler warning.

Comment: The question was originally tagged with C, whereas Arduino uses C++. The only difference is that the cast would be `(enum DisplayItem)(something)` in C instead of `(DisplayItem)(something)` in C++, although both forms should work in C++.